# How to align `<label>` behind transparent `<input>`

Tags: html, css, forms

How do i align `<label>` centered behind transparent `<input>` then set opacity of input onfocus to 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them both in a relatively positioned container, then absolutely position one over the other.

Rough sketch:

```
.container { position: relative; }
.container label { position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0; }
.container input { position: relative; z-index: 2; }
```

You'll need to tweak borders, paddings and margins to suit.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, in theory it should work, thanks for trying

Comment: Yeah, seems to work there. thanks alot. Is there any way i can keep the input background white when input is not empty i have edited your jsfiddle to show you what i mean. HERE> http://jsfiddle.net/3aaFT/

Comment: Only by using JavaScript. You can test the value and modify the classes to which the element belongs whenever the value is modified.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to put placeholder text in an input field. You don't need a separate `<label>` element to do that:

```
<input name="test" placeholder="Example">
```

Comment: No, it sounds like he wants a real label but one which isn't visible when the input has content in it. (Much like the Facebook signup page)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:focus` pseudo class to select the input when it's focused and apply `opacity: 1`.  You can use absolute positioning to have the input appear in front of the label text.

```
label {
    position: relative;
}
input {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
input:focus {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/EHxRr/

However it seems to me that using the `placholder` attribute for the input would have the same effect you are going for.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/EHxRr/2/

Comment: `placeholder` has a defined purpose that is very different from `<label>`. Elements and attributes should be selected for what they say about the content, *not* their effects (which often have unexpected and negative consequences for non-mainstream browsing software).

Comment: @Quentin what is the defined purpose of `placeholder` vs. `<label>`?

Comment: The label represents a caption in a user interface.  — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

Comment: The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has no value. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format. The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.  — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Comment: @Quentin that's great but I don't really understand the difference (other than the fact that the placeholder should be short).  Is the label intended to be longer?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: A label describes what you should goes there (e.g, "street address"). A placeholder is an example of what you can put there (e.g, "123 Main Street").

Comment: The label is supposed to tell you what the field is for. The placeholder is there to help you fill it out correctly. e.g. `<label> Date of Birth <input name="dob" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></label>`